# Obtener los usuarios menores de edad

Tags: laravel

nose si es posible hacer eso, no se me ocurre una forma de lograrlo por mi mismo.
Necesito quitar las reservas de menores de edad

la consulta que ocupo es esta:

```
$reservas = Reservas::where('aceptado', 1)->get();
```

En el CRUD hago un filtro para que me muestre los menores de edad con:

```
       @foreach ($reservas as $reserva)
     @if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($reserva->users->edad)->age <= 18)
 -----RESULTADOS USERES MENORES DE EDAD --------
    @endif
     @endforeach
```

Pero necesito hacerlo directamente desde la consulta  `Reservas::where('aceptado', 1)->get();`

hay forma de hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cómo estás guardando la edad en la base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

No se como estás guardando la edad en la tabla de usuarios, pero asumo que es una fecha.

```
Reservas::where('aceptado', 1)->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->whereRaw('edad <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR');
})->get();
```

Con [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) traemos las reservas que tengan usuarios con una condición específica. La condición se define con un [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw) para poder escribir una consulta de MySQL a mano.

La consulta solo tiene en cuenta usuarios cuya *fecha* (edad) sea menor o igual a la fecha actual ([`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)) menos 18 años ([`- INTERVAL 18 YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals)).